# How can I correct the requests I'm making with socket client api?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm going through an existing code base trying to debug a messaging problem, and while I was tracing code, I found this piece of code

```
import io from "socket.io-client"
import { domain, socketBase } from "../config"
//domain = localhost
//socketBase = http://localhost:5000

const socket = io.connect(domain, { path: socketBase })

export class socketService {
  static introduce(phoneNumber) {
    socket.emit("introduce", phoneNumber)
  }

  static onMessage(callback) {
    socket.on("message-recive", callback)
  }

  static sendMessage(message) {
    socket.emit("message-send", message)
  }

  static sendMedia(message) {
    socket.emit("media-send", message)
  }
}
```

however when I log the socket variable initialized at the beginning I get an object that's not connected. My client told me that it's working, but the code doesn't make sense, because in the network tab I can see get requests being made to this url

```
http://localhosthttp//localhost:5000/socket/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFs6km7
```

but when I correct the syntax to

```
const socket = io.connect(socketBase)
```

I get requests being made to `http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFsCRyK`
but I only get valid responses when I make requests to `http://localhost:5000/socket/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFsCRyK`. Almost the same url but without the `.io`.
Am I doing something wrong here ? I tried using a manager from the client socket api, but I still got the same issue.